# Numpy Histogram expression

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

Please consider the local variable `few_counts`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

few_rolls = np.random.randint(1,7,size=10)
few_counts = np.histogram(few_rolls, bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5))[0]
```

I do not understand why there has to be a 0 in square brackets outside of the histogram expression for the code to run correctly. If I remove it or change the value, the code fails, as shown below:

```py
# Remove [0]
few_counts = np.histogram(few_rolls, bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5))
# Create figure and axes
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,3))
# Code fails here
ax1.bar(np.arange(1,7), few_counts)
```

Can someone explain why it's necessary to add `[0]` outside the histogram function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), `numpy.histogram` returns `hist` and `bin_edges`. `hist` is the values of the histogram, and `bin_edges` are the edges of the bars in the x-axis.

By adding `[0]` at the end of `numpy.histogram(...)`, you are selecting the first array returned by the function. Hence, you are selecting the `hist` array. If you do not do this, you would be passing two arrays as `height` to `ax1.bar()` (i.e. you would be passing both `hist` and `bin_edges` as `height`).

Comment: Thanks. 
With the [0] in place 'few_counts' is of type 'numpy.ndarray'. As you point out, the 0th element of the ndarray accesses the collection.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_ndarray_object.htm

Interestingly, if I take [0] off the expression and print the object type, it changes from ndarray to tuple.

thanks again